# Moderator declined flag for duplicate answer

Tags: discussion

I posted an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282777/try-catch-doesnt-catch-an-exception-thrown-during-an-explicit-wait). The next day I came back to respond to a comment and saw another answer that didn't offer anything new vs my answer. This wasn't a case of I beat the other answerer to it because the time difference was ~18? hours, if I remember correctly. I flagged the other answer as a duplicate and it was

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

The new answer didn't address the actual question. What it did offer was a rewording of what I said and the only difference in code was that he one-lined the first `return`.

What am I missing? What value add does this new answer offer that is new/different enough from mine?

Comment: I don't see it.  Two wrongs don't make a right, maybe you can work off the comment I posted on the question.

Answer (score 5):

It's not exactly a useful answer because the code does the exact same thing as yours, since all it shows is basically a different way to factor the code, like a formatting preference. However, duplicate answers are when content is plagiarized, and this answer is different enough from yours to not quite count as plagiarism. So it doesn't add any new value, but it is not plagiarism. The correct course of action is to downvote for not being useful, not flag for being a duplicate of your answer.

Comment: Duplicate answers are not only when answers are plagiarized. I flagged it because it added no new value. Once a question gets enough answers and you try to add another one, you get a prompt: `Did you read through all the existing answers first to make sure your answer will be contributing something new? Also, please note that you can click the edit link on any of these answers to improve them.` I take that to mean that new answers should actually add something new, not rehash or reword existing answers.

Comment: @JeffC Again, the answer did not add anything new, but the proper course of action is not a flag, it is a downvote. Flagging for moderator attention is for cases where something is actually wrong and action needs to be taken against the post and possibly the user for cases of plagiarism or harmful content, but rehashing or rewording something that's already present, although useless, is not plagiarism or harmful in the way the author of that answer has written their answer. The tooltip on the downvote button includes "This answer is not useful." That is the proper action.